# php text in css tooltip

Tags: php, css, tooltip

What I am trying to do is add information from extracted with php into a css tooltip. The text, instead of appearing inside the tooltip, appears next to the label tag I have. The tooltip appears over the label tag. Here my code so you can probably help me:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<?php
//Connect to the database
require_once("dboconn.php");
$conn=ConnectionFactory::connect();

$query = "SELECT * FROM programmer";
$resultset = $conn->query($query);

function projects($prog_id){
    require_once("dboconn.php");
    $conn=ConnectionFactory::connect();

    $query2= "SELECT * FROM programmer pm INNER JOIN project p ON pm.programmer_id=p.programmer_id WHERE pm.programmer_id=:id";
    $resultset2= $conn->prepare($query2);
    $resultset2->bindValue(":id",$prog_id);
    $resultset2->execute();
    $isthere=false;

    while($row2 = $resultset2->fetch()){
        echo "Working on project ".$row2['project_id'].".";
        $isthere=true;
    }

    if(!$isthere){
        echo "No projects";
    }
}

while ($row = $resultset->fetch())
{
        echo "<p class='col'>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='programmers[]' id='programmer".$row['programmer_id']."' value='".$row['programmer_id']."'>";
        echo "<a href='' class='help tip-below' data-tip='".projects($row['programmer_id'])."'><label for='programmer".$row['programmer_id']."'>".$row['programmer_name']." ".$row['programmer_surname']."</label></a>";
        echo "</p>";
}

?>
```

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `projects()` has no return value (instead you print it, which is bad practice btw)!

Change

```
while($row2 = $resultset2->fetch()){
    echo "Working on project ".$row2['project_id'].".";
    $isthere=true;
}

if(!$isthere){
    echo "No projects";
}
```

To something like this

```
$result = "";
while($row2 = $resultset2->fetch()){
    $result .= "Working on project ".$row2['project_id'].".";
}

if(empty($result)){
    return "No projects";
}
return $result;
```

---

To clarify this, you can think of a function as a calculator maybe. You **input** specific data (an equation e.g.) and it **returns** something (the solution). What happens inside, you don't know and don't really care.

Now back to PHP, the input is clear: the **parameters** (`$prog_id`), but your function has **no return**, instead it just prints something to the screen (what you really shouldn't do outside a development environment). To test this you can use

```
var_dump( projects($some_id) );
```

And it will return `NULL` (because no return was specified), but what you really wanted was a string of some sort.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you very very much for your help. I am quite new to PHP so I'm just learning a lot of things. Thanks for helping me out, I'll keep in mind what you said.